# How to structure classes to collect data, analyse data, summarize analysis for quick reference

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, class-design

Stackoverflow,

How would you structure code to gather a collection of data within an outer collection, and return a frequency distribution by data type (i.e. each data type within the collection of data)?  I know this problem must have been solved many times. However, I can not locate an answer.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

By way of example:

- you have a classroom of 30 students,
- each student completes exams
- each exam is comprised of many questions
- data is collected on each question (e.g. question response (integer), time taken to complete question (TimeSpan))
- For the classroom, for each exam (e.g. question no.1), for each question (e.g. question no.1), for each data type collected (e.g. question response) you want to retrieve a frequency distribution (e.g. 10 responses = 1, 15 responses = 2, 5 responses = 3, 0 responses = 4).

Below is my thinking thus far... which is evidently incorrect:
Collecting the data **seemed** straight forward with:

- Class Class
- Student Class
- Exam Class
- Question Class: IEnumerable (if integer and TimeSpan values were converted to double)

Resulting in:

- one Class instance comprised of a list many Student instances
- each Student instance comprised of a list many Exam instances
- each exam instance comprised of a list many Question instances
- each question instance with properties (e.g. question response (integer), time taken to complete question (TimeSpan))

Returning the frequency for data collected on a question is where I came unstuck:

- Benchmark Class
- DataType Class (i.e. the properties from the Question class. I am unsure of this.)
- Distribution Class

Resulting in:

- one Benchmark instance comprised of a Dictionary>> ???

Using LINQ, in turn grab each question from each student:

```
List<Exam> Exams = from student in classroom
    where student.examNumber == "x"
    select student.exam.ToList();

List<Question> Questions = from question in exams
    where question.Number == "x"
    select question.ToList();
```

With a list of responses to the same question on the same exam:

- for each dataType collected (hence the IEnumerable)
- get the series of dataType
- Using series as a parameter instantiate new distribution
- add to dictionary.

I am aware this solution is incomplete and incorrect.  Again, any guidance would be appreciated.

Regards
Shannon

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to wrap my head around your example... but here's a concept loosely based on real code I'm using to do complex LINQ queries for reporting...

```
   var linqAnswers = from question in Questions
                            group question by question.Answer into grpAnswer
                            select new
                            {
                                answer = grpAnswer.Key,
                                count = grpAnswer.Count(),
                                data = ProcessAnswerFrequencyData(Questions, grpAnswer)
                            };


 protected IEnumerable<QuestionAnswerChartPoint> ProcessAnswerFrequencyData(IEnumerable<Question> list, IGrouping<string, Question> grp)
{
    //Do more processing on the group and return a reporting list.
}
```

That code is ad-hoc, untested, invalid, conceptual garbage... but maybe it will put you in the right direction.